# Setting Combobox Value for RowEditing Editor in Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, extjs5, sencha-architect

I am kinda facing an interesting problem where my combobox is behaving weird.

I have a grid with three columns ID , Name , Associated Part.

I have enabled Rowediting plugin and editors for ID is textfield(EditID), Name is textfield(EditName) and Associated Part is combobox(EditPartCombo).

I have a button called Update.

When I select any row in the grid and press Update, rowediting starts at that exact position.

EditID and EditName shows default values that has been selected but EditCombo populates as Blank.

Code on Update button:

```
{
text: 'Update Part',

handler: function(btn){

var grid = btn.up('grid');
var selection = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection();


if(selection.length > 0){

alert(selection[0].get('ID_PART'));
Ext.getCmp('EditPartCombo').setValue(selection[0].get('ID_PART'));

var rowEditing = grid.getPlugin('RowEditPlugin');
var rowno = grid.store.indexOf(selection[0]);
rowEditing.cancelEdit();

rowEditing.startEdit(rowno, 1);  
}

else{ Ext.Msg.alert('Error' , 'Please Select any Row'); } 
}
```

Following alert gives me proper value of selected column:

```
alert(selection[0].get('ID_PART'));
```

but somehow it does net set the value to combobox.

Same thing works fine if I open a new pop-up window and apply the value to combobox created on window.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might be a sencha limitation. Have you checked sencha bugs forum?

Comment: Have you configured **displayField** and/or **valueField** options on your ComboBox? If not it could explain why you are experiencing blank values. See [ExtJS ComboBox Docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox)